# Jquery delay problem

Tags: jquery

Why this delay of Jquery animation does not work as it should be?

```
$(" .inner").stop().delay(1000).animate({height:'142px'},{queue:false, duration:600});
```

Is there any other way to delay this animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its because you've got

```
queue:false
```

which means its not using the default fx queue which delay() acts on by default.  Try taking out queue: false

The [documentation for delay(duration, [ queueName ] ) says](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

> queueNameA string containing the name of the queue. Defaults to fx, the standard effects queue.

The [documentation for animate(properties, options )](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) says

> queue: A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately.